# How to move saved location of xcode files without messing up references

Tags: xcode

Since this is my first app I naively have all my xcode files (swift code, assets, and storyboard) all saved to my desktop. Is there someway I can move it (or duplicated backups) to another location like github or google drive without messing up all the references?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with saving stuff to the desktop. But what should be on the desktop should be a *project folder*, with an organization like this:

```
Desktop
    MyProject (this is the project folder)
        MyProject.xcodeproj (this is the project)
        MyProject (this is a group folder)
            [everything else]
```

That is the situation that Xcode will create for you by default. And if that is indeed the situation, then all is well. You can just drag the project folder elsewhere and nothing will break. You can put it under git control and upload it to github and nothing will break. You can clone from github to another computer and nothing will break. This is how people operate every day, all the time.

(Don't put it on google drive, that's the kiss of death.)

If that is *not* the situation, then the situation is so bad that you would be better off starting all over again. It is possible to move stuff into the project folder, but then you have to alert the project to what you've done, and that can be an error-prone task for a beginner.